# On existence of conjecture relating prime zeta function:

Tags: analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, zeta-functions

There is an article on Wikipedia about  prime zeta function (PZF):

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_zeta_function

In that article , there is table of fairly accurate values of PZF for different $s$ .

We all know that

$\zeta(2n)=π^n\mathbb{Q}$.

So my question is :

> Are there conjectured values of PZF such that they are the combination of well known transcendental numbers like $\pi$ and $e$ (like $\zeta(2n)$ above)  and are very close to values given in the article ?

Comment: since these numerical PZF values are on OESIS, I presume if one of these had a closed form expression it would be mentioned there, don't you think so?

Comment: That would be OEIS, e.g., https://oeis.org/A085548 for digits of prime zeta function at 2.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:As montioned above in the comment by @Carlo Beenakker , the formula is already montioned in the OEIS using Möbius Function which it is  $ PZF(p)= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mu(n)\log \zeta(p^n)}{n}$ its seems that is deduced using [Moibus  inversion formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_inversion_formula) with $p$ is a prime number you want to evaluate its zeta prime function